# DataGridView изменяет размер ячеек

Tags: c#, winforms

Если в DataGridView больше строк, чем он может в себя поместить(появляется полоса прокрутки сбоку). Но проблема в том что изменяется еще и ширина столбцов. У меня в коде ширина каждого столбца задается так: `Column1.Width = dataGridView1.Width / 5`, где 5 - количество столбцов. Все работает, пока столбцы помещаются в DataGridView, но в противоположном случае `Column1.Width =...` не работает - к автоматически ширине прибавляется примерно 10.

Comment: там вроде в свойствах грида можно это отключить

Comment: Используйте `dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill)`. [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autoresizecolumns?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, все работает